# How to measure Golang integration test coverage?

Tags: testing, go, code-coverage, test-coverage

I am trying to use `go test -cover` to measure the test coverage of a service I am building. It is a REST API and I am testing it by spinning it up, making test HTTP requests and reviewing the HTTP responses. These tests are not part of the packages of the services and `go tool cover` returns 0% test coverage. Is there a way to get the actual test coverage? I would expect a best-case scenario test on a given endpoint to cover at least 30-50% of the code for specific endpoint handler, and by adding more tests for common error to improve this further.

Comment: A useful utility for accurate code coverage reporting for Golang: https://github.com/ory/go-acc

Comment: Thank you, Sergei. I was not aware of it, will check it out!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was pointed at the `-coverpkg` directive, which does what I need - measures the test coverage in a particular package, even if tests that use this package and not part of it. For example:

```
$ go test -cover -coverpkg mypackage ./src/api/...
ok      /api    0.190s  coverage: 50.8% of statements in mypackage
ok      /api/mypackage   0.022s  coverage: 0.7% of statements in mypackage
```

compared to

```
$ go test -cover ./src/api/...
ok      /api    0.191s  coverage: 71.0% of statements
ok      /api/mypackage   0.023s  coverage: 0.7% of statements
```

In the example above, I have tests in `main_test.go` which is in `package main` that is using `package mypackage`. I am mostly interested in the coverage of `package mypackage` since it contains 99% of the business logic in the project.

I am quite new to Go, so it is quite possible that this is not the best way to measure test coverage via integration tests.

Comment: Great! I'm just linking this [relevant golang-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/fnDBPPUDdQ4).

Comment: Thanks, Simon. This is indeed what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

you can run go test in a way that creates coverage html pages. like this:

```
go test -v -coverprofile cover.out ./...
go tool cover -html=cover.out -o cover.html
open cover.html
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want coverage you need to run `go test -cover`.

However it is easy enough to add a flag which you can pass in which will enable these extra tests, so you can make them part of your test suite but don't run them normally.

So add a command line flag in your `whatever_test.go`

```
var integrationTest = flag.Bool("integration-test", false, "Run the integration tests")
```

Then in each test do something like this

```
func TestSomething(t *testing.T){
    if !*integrationTest {
        t.Skip("Not running integration test")
    }
    // Do some integration testing
}
```

Then to run the integration tests

```
go run -cover -integration-test
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this is not exactly what I need. The problem was that the percentage of coverage does not cover the code in other packages of the project. I will update my question to reflect that and make it clearer.

Comment: @antonevangelatov I see what you mean!  I'll leave this answer just in case anyone finds it useful, and I note `-coverpkg` in your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

2015:

> These tests are not part of the packages of the services and go tool cover returns 0% test coverage

March 2023, [Go 1.20 Cover](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#cover) adds:

> Go 1.20 supports collecting code coverage profiles for programs (applications and integration tests), as opposed to just unit tests.
>
> To collect coverage data for a program, build it with `go build`'s `-cover` flag, then run the resulting binary with the environment variable `GOCOVERDIR` set to an output directory for coverage profiles.
> See the '[coverage for integration tests](https://go.dev/testing/coverage)' landing page for more on how to get started. For details on the design and implementation, see the [proposal](https://golang.org/issue/51430).

As documented in "[Code coverage for Go integration tests](https://go.dev/blog/integration-test-coverage)" with

> With the 1.20 release, Go’s coverage tooling is no longer limited to package tests, but supports collecting profiles from larger integration tests.

Example:

```bash
$ go build -cover -o myprogram.exe myprogram.go
$ mkdir somedata
$ GOCOVERDIR=somedata ./myprogram.exe
I say "Hello, world." and "see ya"
$ ls somedata
covcounters.c6de772f99010ef5925877a7b05db4cc.2424989.1670252383678349347
covmeta.c6de772f99010ef5925877a7b05db4cc
```

And

> ### Working with coverage data files
>
> Go 1.20 introduces a new tool, '`covdata`', that can be used to read and manipulate coverage data files from a `GOCOVERDIR` directory.

```bash
$ go tool covdata percent -i=somedata
    main    coverage: 100.0% of statements
    mydomain.com/greetings  coverage: 100.0% of statements
```

Comment: While not wrong this is basically just copy/paste from the docs

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.