# How to get Integration Test Coverage for GoLang Microservice

Tags: go, microservices, code-coverage, go-testing

I created a couple of Rest API based Microservices running of different ports of a server.
Then i wrote a Test code that actually sends a Rest API call over HTTP to serviceA (which in turn calls serviceB), and gets its response, decodes it and compares it against the expected response.
This all works OK, but the test shows 0.0% coverage when i ran it as `go test -cover`

```
src/
|--serviceA/
|     |--main.go
|     |--integration_test.go
|--serviceB/
      |--main.go
```

I manually ran each service.

```
go run serviceA/main.go   // Listens on port X
go run serviceB/main.go   // Listens on port Y
```

My `integration_test.go` has a `TestFunc()` that literally calls one REST API endpoint of `serviceA/main.go` using `http.Client{}` and `http.NewRequest()` and then examines the response.
Response is as expected but coverage of `serviceA` is 0.0%, which should not be the case as it actually sent some data back so multiple lines were executed.

The services A & B are not a lib package so i couldn't use the `-coverpkg` cmd as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364103)

Probably I am looking for tool that can give coverage of a blackbox component/service.

Comment: Are these "API calls" made via an HTTP request from one service to the other?

Comment: Yes. Rest Calls over HTTP.  TestCode ----> ServiceA ----> ServiceB

Comment: I am not sure that go cover supports coverage with integration tests (via HTTP calls). I thought it was just for units tests / `_test.go` files. Are Service A and Service B, in the same binary as TestCode?

Comment: you are right. So what is the way to get coverage for integration tests ?

Comment: I think the coverage comes from unit tests. And for an integration test, I would think (although I am no expert) to choose an acceptance criteria that _means something_. 100% code coverage doesn't mean much if the application doesn't do what it is supposed to.

Comment: [Start your servers in the tests](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewServer), not in their own processes. You will have to move the handlers/routers out of their main packages so you can import them in the test.

Comment: @Peter, Thanks for the comment. Calling the handlers directly from test code is the unit test way. I am not sure if this qualifies as a integration test / component test ?